# HBase - snapshots performance

Tags: performance, hbase, snapshot

I am working on a use case where we need to take several snapshots (80-100) of a table in HBase, lets call it "data". We want the capability of reading from these snapshots at any given time. So we would need to clone the snapshot and make use of it as a new table (for example "data_v01", "data_v02" etc. I am unable to figure out whether having multiple snapshots affect the performance of the original "data" table.

From what I understood from reading HBase documentation, HBase doesn't copy the data when a snapshot is taken nor when a new table is created ("cloned") from a snapshot. To me this seems like HBase creates a base set of HFiles and then changes are tracked in the form or something similar to WAL. If this is true, and the base snapshot is 100 days old, this would mean the changes would be many. Is my understanding correct? I couldn't find too much reference around this other than https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#ops.snapshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may already know, HBase consistency is given by the collection of `HFile` and `WAL` files. A snapshot is merely the list of all HFiles in the table at the time of the snapshot (whether or not the snapshot forced WAL and memstores flush) .That's why snapshot is very fast and cheap to create - all it does is to save a list of paths to files. This means that the files **must not be deleted** in case of compaction, and instead are moved to archive folder until no snapshot is referencing them (very much like GC). In some cases this might lead to storage overhead.

> I am unable to figure out whether having multiple snapshots affect the performance of the original "data" table.

Creating a table from a snapshot has nothing to do with the original table. The fact that both tables might be sharing some HFiles has no meaning since HFiles are immutable.

> ...(if) the base snapshot is 100 days old, this would mean (that the data is outdated)

Yes this is correct. The snapshot will only see the HFiles that existed when it was created.